# Miximum Likelihood - using Optim package

Tags: julia

Dear users of the language **julia**. I have a problem when using the `optimize` function of the **Optim** package. What is the error of the code below?

```
using Optim
using Distributions

rng = MersenneTwister(1234);

d = Weibull(1,1)
x = rand(d,1000)


function pdf_weibull(x, lambda, k)  
    k/lambda * (x/lambda).^(k-1) * exp((-x/lambda)^k)

end


function obj(x::Vector, lambda, k)
    soma = 0
    for i in x
        soma = soma + log(pdf_weibull(i,lambda,k))
    end
    -soma
end

obj(x, pars) = obj(x, pars...)

optimize(vars -> obj(x, vars...), [1.0,1.0])
```

**Output**

```
julia> optimize(vars -> obj(x, vars...), [1.0,1.0])
ERROR: DomainError:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.
Stacktrace:
 [1] nan_dom_err at ./math.jl:300 [inlined]
 [2] ^ at ./math.jl:699 [inlined]
 [3] (::##2#4)(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64) at ./<missing>:0
 [4] pdf_weibull(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64) at ./REPL[6]:2
 [5] obj(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64, ::Float64) at ./REPL[7]:4
 [6] (::##5#6)(::Array{Float64,1}) at ./REPL[11]:1
 [7] value(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/NLSolversBase/src/interface.jl:19
 [8] initial_state(::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}, ::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/Optim/src/multivariate/solvers/zeroth_order/nelder_mead.jl:139
 [9] optimize(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/Optim/src/multivariate/optimize/optimize.jl:25
 [10] #optimize#151(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Tuple{##5#6}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/Optim/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:62
 [11] #optimize#148(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/Optim/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:52
 [12] optimize(::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /home/pedro/.julia/v0.6/Optim/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:52
 [13] macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:97 [inlined]
 [14] (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:73
```

It is a simple problem to obtain the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters that index the weibull distribution.

Best regards.

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get an error message? If so, please tell us what it is. Do you get unexpected results? If so, what are they and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect the maximum likelihood estimates which in this case will estimate `lambda` and `k` by approximately **1**.

Comment: Have you tried making the changes that the error message suggests? If so, show us what you've tried

Comment: I have not tried because I just do not understand why the first error message refers to the complex numbers. Could you explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason of your problem is that your definition of `pdf_weibull` is incorrect. Here is a corrected definition:

```
function pdf_weibull(x, lambda, k)
    k/lambda * (x/lambda)^(k-1) * exp(-(x/lambda)^k)
end
```

Note that I have moved `-` sign in `exp` part of the expression. If you change this all will work as expected.

Now - why does Julia complain with `DomainError`. The reason is that because of the error in your code you try to calculate the value of something like `(-1.0)^0.5`. In Julia `^` is implemented in type stable way. This means, in particular, that when it is passed `Float64` as both arguments it guarantees to return `Float64` or throw an error. Clearly `(-1.0)^0.5` cannot be computed in real domain - that is why an error is thrown. If you passed `(-1+0im)^0.5` then there would be no error as we are passing a complex number to `^` so the result can also be complex number in a type stable way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In fact as you can see, I'm just curious about Julia. Actually I'm an R programmer, I have packages in R and I do not understand Julia. Julia seems to me to be a flexible language that deserves great attention by the statistical community. Thanks again.

Comment: In R your original function would produce `NaN`. Actually I prefer to see an error to `NaN` as `NaN` would silently propagate and it would be much harder to pinpoint where the problem is (I have used R for 15 years before switching to Julia and such behavior of Julia has saved me a lot of time since the switch). Actually, I knew for 99% what the problem was just by seeing `DomainError` - before reading the code I could tell that most probably you raised a negative number to a fractional power.

Comment: Yes, the production of NaN may produce errors that accumulate during dota the simulation. Currently I use R and use **Rcpp** when I want to improve the performance of some function. My big problem is that I always end up wanting to improve all functions using C++. So I end up using more C++ than R. I find R a very flexible language. I will in parallel study Julia and perhaps in the future I implement some libraries in Julia. I may fall in love with this new language.